# Need a count of this Interbase Distinct SQL

Tags: sql, interbase

I have the following working Distinct Interbase SQL on the two fields.  I need to modify it to just return a count of these distinct records.

```
select distinct ap.propertyuid, ap.adjpropertyuid
from adjproperty ap
where ap.payyear = 2019
order by 1, 2
```

Data

propertyUID adjpropertyUID  payyear

15              21              2019

15              22              2019

16          23          2019

16          23          2019

16          25          2019

17          33          2019

17          33          2019

Should return a count of five,

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result. All as formatted text, no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(distinct ap.propertyuid || ap.adjpropertyuid)
  from adjproperty ap
 where ap.payyear = 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?:

```
select count(distinct ap.propertyuid), count(distinct ap.adjpropertyuid)
from adjproperty ap
where ap.payyear = 2019
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: Can't count the fields separately as the two fields together make up the distinct statement.

Comment: you can count them combined like count(distinct ap.propertyuid || ap.adjpropertyuid)

Comment: MarEll - you got it.  If you change this into an answer instead of a comment I will mark it as THE answer and include the exact syntax I used it to solve my issue.  Thanks